# how to get input char from user?

Tags: c, input, char

So i'm supposed to use a while loop to read two strings and do some operations to the strings. The user should be able to enter multiple string pairs until he enters exit. How do i accept the string instead of hard copying something as this function.?

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{    
    char string[3], stringSec[2];
    string[0] = 'c';
    string[1] = 'a';
    string[2] = 't';
    stringSec[0] = 'c';
    stringSec[1] = 's';
    int array[3][4];

    // some functions...

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey @AbeerSec, if my answer has helped you, would you consider accepting it? Accepting an answer shows the community that it has solved your problem, and helps future readers with theirs. If you don't know how to accept an answer, there's a useful [faq meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` to read the string and `strcmp` to check if it equals "exit":

```
while (strcmp(string, "exit"))
{
    fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);
    fgets(secString, sizeof(secString), stdin);

    // perform operations on strings
}
```

Explanation:

- `strcmp` returns 0 if the two strings match. In the example above the loop will continue as long as it doesn't return 0.
- `fgets` reads a certain amount of bytes (2nd argument) from a file (3rd argument) into a string (1st argument).

Notes:

- `fgets` does not remove the trailing newline from the string read. You can remove it by adding `string[strlen(string)-1] = '\0';` after reading.
- you must `#include <string.h>` to use `strcmp`.

Comment: This is the answer to go with. Note, to use `strcmp` and the `string` type you need to include `string.h`.